# PHP ODBC returns less rows than expected

Tags: php

I am using following code

```
$connection = odbc_connect("****** details I cant disclose ******");
if ($Connection)
{
 $result = odbc_exec($connection, "***** sql query *****");
 print (odbc_num_rows($result));
}
```

I am using sql server database. 
this was fine for last one month, but suddenly this is returning far less count of rows that actually it should. if I copy query run it as it is on sql server console it returns me exact expected row count, but if run same query through odbc in php I am getting far less count. I am novice to php never faced this issue before.

Comment: firstly check if the `odbc` drivers are still being supported in the version your server uses for PHP. If you recently updated your server, this could of had a knock on effect. I'd always suggest to anyone using either `odbc` or `myql` to use either `mysqli` or preferably `pdo` - it isn't hard to learn. The connection time could be dying before the SQL completes due to the old method you're using

Comment: many ODBC drivers return -1, so in general odbc_num_rows() is not reliable. instead of that try using odbc_fetch_array() with your own counter.

Comment: Have you considered either printing the data to see if the rows are as many as you expect and it may be the query returning less or more data than you expected? Have you also considered using a "SELECT COUNT(*)" query?